# Change file and directory permission on files copied to samba share

Tags: server, permissions, samba

I have an ubuntu server sharing a folder using samba. What I need is that my shared folder is writable on root only by a specific user, while the **BACKUP** folder contained within this share is writable by anyone.

I managed to achieve this with the following configuration file, and setting the permissions of the **BACKUP** directory to 777

```
[test]
path = <path_folder>
guest ok = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
browseable = yes
create mask = 0755
directory mask = 2777
force directory mode = 2777
inherit acls = yes
inherit permissions = yes
```

The folder structure is as follows:
[image]

Everything works correctly except for the files that are copied into the **BACKUP** directory, to which the **nobody** user and the **nogroup** group are assigned. What I would like is that once I've copied the file samba will assign them by default the user and the group **my_user**.

[image]

The only solution I have currently found is to use the `force user =` and `force group =` options, which however allow anyone to write to the root folder as well, regardless of whether the user who is copying the data is logged in or not, which I wish could only happen within the **BACKUP** folder.

**EDIT**

I managed to fix it as I wanted by managing permissions via acl, modifying the config file as follows:

```
[test]
path = <path>
read only = no
guest ok = yes
inherit owner = yes
inherit acls = yes
inherit permissions = yes
vfs objects = acl_xattr
map acl inherit = yes
store dos attributes = yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Create TWO shares, using different paths.

Comment: I wanted to avoid this solution, since there are actually **more than one folder** and not just the **BACKUP** folder as written in the question. I'd better like to fix it with a combination of linux permissions and samba configuration

Comment: OK, try adding 'vfs objects = acl_xattr' to the global portion of your smb.conf. Ensure that the 'acl' and 'attr' packages are installed. Remove most of what you have added to the share (you only need the 'path' and read only = no) then read up on 'setfacl' and 'getfacl'.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, everything is working fine now. If you want to edit the answer for upvote plus confirmation of the answer, go ahead.